# Question on cart_cartthrob_cart table

Tags: cartthrob

Can anyone explain what the cart field is on this table - looks like some sort of either serialized or encrypted field.

Answer (score 0):

The field is an encrypted copy of an array containing the non-default items in the cart.

It is created by the `update_cart` function which is defined within the `Cart_model` class.

HTH